# Assigning weights to different features in R

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, quanteda

Is it possible to assign weights to different features before formulating a DFM in R?

Consider this example in R

`str="apple is better than banana"
mydfm=dfm(str, ignoredFeatures = stopwords("english"), verbose = FALSE)`

DFM mydfm looks like:

```
docs apple better banana
text1  1      1     1
```

But, I want to assign weights(apple:5, banana:3) beforehand, so that DFM mydfm looks like:

```
docs apple better banana
text1  5      1     3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, however you can easily do it afterwards:

```
library(quanteda)
str <- "apple is better than banana"
mydfm <- dfm(str, ignoredFeatures = stopwords("english"), verbose = FALSE)
idx <- which(names(weights) %in% colnames(mydfm))
mydfm[, names(weights)[idx]] <-  mydfm[, names(weights)[idx]] %*% diag(weights[idx])
mydfm
# 1 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#        features
# docs    apple better banana
#   text1     5      1      3
```

Comment: Yes,it works, thanks! 
One additional doubt...
I wanted to import weights from a .csv file where one column has all the features and the adjacent column has their respective weights.
`ft=data$features`
`wt=data$weights`
Can I generate a vector of this form `weights <- c("apple"=5, "banana"=3)` using ft and wt object.

Comment: You're welcome. To your question: `weights <- setNames(wt, ft)`

Comment: `mydfm[, names(weights)]` only works if `names(weights)` is subset of features in `str <- "apple is better than banana"`, else it gives an error.

I tried with `weights <- c("apple"=5, "banana"=3, "grapes"=4)` on the same string and it gives this error 
`Error in intI(j, n = x@Dim[2], dn[[2]], give.dn = FALSE) : 
  invalid character indexing`

Answer (score 0):

This points to the need to add an option to the `weight` method for dfm-class, to make this easier and more importantly not to strip the class of dfm from the sparse matrix.  The dfm also has a `@weights` slot in the object that is designed to keep a record of how it was weighted, so this information could/should also be preserved.

@lukeA's solution drops the dfm class twice (not his or your fault but mine!!), once in the `%*%` and again in the `<-`. The first can be avoided by using column-wise recycling and a standard `*` instead of the matrix multiplication `%*%`, since I don't think a method has been written for dfm-class for `%*%` (which is why it defaults to the `sparseMatrix` method).  The second cannot currently be avoided if you reassign sub-matrix elements, but can be avoided if you simply replace one dfm-class object object with another.

To make the new dfm-class object in a way that preserves the class, this would work (and here I have made the problem slightly more complex by adding a second document and another feature):

```
str <- c("apple is better than banana", "banana banana apple much better")
weights <- c(apple = 5, banana = 3, much = 0.5)
mydfm <- dfm(str, ignoredFeatures = stopwords("english"), verbose = FALSE)

# use name matching for indexing, sorts too, returns NA where no match is found
newweights <- weights[features(mydfm)]
# reassign 1 to non-matched NAs
newweights[is.na(newweights)] <- 1

# works because of column-wise recycling of the vector
mydfm * newweights
## Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 4 features.
## 2 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
##        features
## docs    apple better banana much
##   text1     5    3.0      5  0  
##   text2     1    0.5      2  0.5
```

One more note:  I'd encourage the use dfm-class-specific methods for extracting things like the column names, e.g. `features(mydfm)` rather than `colnames(mydfm)`, even though these will probably remain equivalent.