# Assigning different numeric weights to different terms in quanteda dfm does not work

Tags: r, quanteda

I am new to text analytics and currently trying out #Quanteda package in R for my needs. I want to assign different numeric weights for some specific and test the model accuracy. I tried the approach mentioned in other thread here to do this by preserving the dfm class 
[Assigning weights to different features in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36815926/assigning-weights-to-different-features-in-r/39840804#39840804) but could not get the correct output. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is what I tried

```
##install.packages("quanteda")
require(quanteda)
str <- c("apple is better than banana", "banana banana apple much  
better","much much better new banana")

weights <- c(apple = 5, banana = 3, much = 0.5)
myDfm <- dfm(str, remove = stopwords("english"), verbose = FALSE)

#output
##Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 5 features.
##3 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
##   features
##docs    apple better banana much new
##text1     1      1      1    0   0
##text2     1      1      2    1   0
##text3     0      1      1    2   1

newweights <- weights[featnames(myDfm)]
# reassign 1 to non-matched NAs
newweights[is.na(newweights)] <- 1

# this does not works for me - see the output
myDfm * newweights

##output
##Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 5 features.
##3 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
##   features
##docs    apple better banana much new
##text1     5    0.5    1.0    0   0
##text2     1    1.0    6.0    5   0
##text3     0    5.0    0.5    2   1
```

Environment Details

platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
   arch           x86_64
   os             mingw32
   system         x86_64, mingw32
   status
   major          3
   minor          2.2
   year           2015
   month          08
   day            14
   svn rev        69053
   language       R
   version.string R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
   nickname       Fire Safety

Comment: And please file an issue for this at https://github.com/kbenoit/quanteda/issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This apparently has something to do with the `*` operator in the **Matrix** package on which the dfm class is based.  This works:

```
> matrix(1:6, nrow = 3) * c(2, 3)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2   12
[2,]    6   10
[3,]    6   18
```

but this does not:

```
> Matrix::Matrix(matrix(1:6, nrow = 3)) * c(2, 3)
Error in Matrix(matrix(1:6, nrow = 3)) * c(2, 3) : 
  length of 2nd arg does not match dimension of first
```

Until we get this fixed, here is a workaround: make the weight vector correspond element-by-element to the dfm.

```
myDfm * rep(newweights, each = ndoc(myDfm))
## Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 5 features.
## 3 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
##        features
## docs    apple better banana much new
##   text1     5      1      3  0     0
##   text2     5      1      6  0.5   0
##   text3     0      1      3  1.0   1
```

**Updated:**

This is not a bug but a feature, and has to do with how the vector `newweights` is recycled to conform to the matrix that it is being multiplied with.  R recycles this vector using column-major order, so it is creating the following matrix where which works in this example (although not as you want it to), to perform element-by-element multiplication:

```
matrix(rep(newweights, 3), nrow = 3)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
## [1,]    5  0.5  1.0    1  3.0
## [2,]    1  1.0  3.0    5  0.5
## [3,]    3  5.0  0.5    1  1.0
```

If you want to use your original strategy, this will work:

```
t(t(myDfm) * newweights)
## Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 5 features (26.7% sparse).
## 3 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
##        features
## docs    apple better banana much new
##   text1     5      1      3  0     0
##   text2     5      1      6  0.5   0
##   text3     0      1      3  1.0   1
```

because the recycling occurs now over features and not over documents.